# Do I close a question when it turns out there is no answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question [How does Feed import get a list of the CSV fields to map to content type fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115453/how-does-feed-import-get-a-list-of-the-csv-fields-to-map-to-content-type-fields) and it turns out that Feeds CSV import doesn't support what I want although Feeds SQL import does?

Do I close it, or wait for Feeds CSV to add the feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to close your questions, unless you are getting a large amount of bad answers or something like that.
If you have an acceptable answer you can accept it, but it is perfectly ok if some time in the future someone adds another answer based on new information (maybe after the feature has been added to that module).

These potential future answers could make your question even more useful to other people in future.